# How can I show only the records that satisfy 2 different conditions under the same table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table with over 1,000,000 rows, and I am trying to return ONLY the records with the same [name] and have both NY = 1 and KS  = 1, even though those will be in separate rows. For this example:

[image]

I want the query to return both records for James, because they both have NY = 1 and KS = 1, but if NY != 1 or KS != 1 for james, then I don't want the query to return it

Comment: Please update your question with your best attempt at resolving the problem.  Also, please add a tag for your specific type of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way, but you could give this a shot.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    your_table AS a
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT TRUE
        FROM your_table AS x
        WHERE
            a.number = x.number
            AND x.KS = 1
    )
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT TRUE
        FROM your_table AS x
        WHERE
            a.number = x.number
            AND x.NY = 1
    )
```

Comment: Yes.  I would only add that table aliases aren't needed in the subquery.  Whether or not you say `AS x`, it can read `where a.number = number and NY = 1`.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden I would expect some database management systems to have issues with that, being that the same column name exists in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want rows where one of these values is set:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE (x.NY = 1 AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM t t2
               WHERE t2.number = t.number AND x.KS = 1
              )
      ) AND
      (x.KS = 1 AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM t t2
               WHERE t2.number = t.number AND x.NY= 1
              )
      );
```

However, window functions might be a good bet:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(ny) over (partition by number) as num_ny,
             sum(ks) over (partition by number) as num_ks
      from t
     ) t
where num_ny > 0 and num_ks > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table1 as table
(
sname varchar(50),
permno int,
symbol int,
groupdate  date
)
insert into @table1(sname,permno,symbol,groupdate)
values
('ashan',1,0,'2019-01-01'),
('re',2,1,'2019-01-01'),
('saman',1,0,'2019-01-01'),
('ashan',0,1,'2019-01-01'),
('saman',1,1,'2019-01-01')

select * from @table1 a
inner join
(select x.sname from
(
select sname,count(sname)as xs
from @table1 group by sname 
having count(sname)>1
)x)b on
a.sname=b.sname
where permno=1 and symbol=1
```

Comment: the query return duplicate value and then apply condition to where cause what u want